# Rails generate url for match named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, match, spree, named

How can i generate url for named match route:

`match '/confirm_email' => 'landing_controller#index', :as => 'frontend_confirm_url', via: [:get]`

using something like this:

- `<%= link_to 'frontend_confirm_url', frontend_confirm_url_url %>`
- `Rails.application.routes.frontend_confirm_url_url`

doesn't work, maybe because i'm using Spree as an engine, and trying to resolve paths from it's mailer?

Comment: Would help to remove the `_url` from `fronend_confirm_url`, no?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out, you need to use:

`<%= link_to 'frontend_confirm_url', main_app.frontend_confirm_url_url %>`